Lang's Algebra: Chapter 3, Exercise 13 (a) on p. 168
The exercise states that:

Let $M$ be a projective finite module over the Dedekind domain $\mathfrak{o}$. Show that there exist free modules $F$ and $F'$ such that $F\subset M\subset F'$, and $F$, $F'$ have the same rank, which is called rank of $M$

I found that maximal number of linearly independent subset, for instance $\{v_i\}$ of $M$ is uniquely determined by the fact that

For $S$ is complement of $(0)$ then $S^{-1}M$ is free(vector space) over $S^{-1}\mathfrak{o}$, and $\{v_i\}$ are linearly independent over $\mathfrak{o}$ iff $\{v_i/1\}$ are linearly independent over $S^{-1}\mathfrak{o}$

and also it is the only possible number of rank we want.
Now it remains to find free module $F'$ containing $M$ that has same rank (as number of basis) to $F$(generated by $\{v_i\}$).
But I cannot find such $F'$. So let me ask you how can I find it
Since I used only the fact so far that $\mathfrak{o}$ is integral domain and $M$ is torsion-free, it needs to use the other conditions (projectivity of $M$ or Dedekindness of $\mathfrak{o}$), but I have no idea.

Indeed, most of the conditions are not needed. You only need that $\mathfrak o$ is an integral domain and $M$ is finitely generated and torsion free. Work inside $V = M\otimes\operatorname{Frac}(\mathfrak o)=S^{-1}M$. Then if $v_1,\dots,v_n\in M$ is a maximal linear independent subset, set $F=\langle v_1,\dots,v_n\rangle$. Then there is $0\ne d\in\mathfrak o$ such that $dM\subset F$ (take a common multiple of all the denominators of the coefficients when writing generating elements for $M$ as $\operatorname{Frac}(\mathfrak o)$-linear combinations of the $v_i$). Then $F'=\frac1dF$ works.
